# Implementing pipe using threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, pipe

I am trying implement a pipe with functions read,write,close.
My main creates 2 threads, one reads from an array and writes to pipe and the other read from pipe and writes to stdout. I am using a simple circular buffer as a pipe and I used Peterson's algorithm to synchronize the two of them.

My main should wait either for them to finish their operation or receive a "quit" input from stdin in which case it should call pipe_close() and terminate the 2 threads by causing them to return

How am I supposed to get input from stdin without blocking? How can I make the threads terminate? Should I use something like Lamports algorithm to synchronize all 3 of them?

Note: I can't use any functions from pthread.h except create

```
void *myread(void *par) {
  //read char from array store in c
  write_to_pipe(c)
}

void *mywrite(void *par) {
  read_from_pipe(&c);
  //print to stdout
}

main() {
  //create threads
  //wait until theads return or "quit" is written in stdin, call pipe_close and cause threads to return
}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: As a start, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question isn't ready for asking here yet, since it is very open-ended and unspecific.

Comment: By "get input from stdin without blocking", do you mean you want to put the tty in raw mode?  Generally, if you `read` from a file descriptor, no blocking will occur if data is available.  I suspect you are conflating stdin with a tty.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to get into signals, and non-block IO, consider forking another thread that will wait for STDIN, and will notify the main three to exit.

Answer (score 0):

This questions sounds like a school assignment. If it is, you should ask a teacher for help.

You can't get input from stdin without blocking the thread that is reading from **stdin**. What I would do is set up two pointers for your circular buffer. One for the *stdin* thread and one for the *stdout* thread. After *stdin* has written data to the buffer it should update it's pointer to point to its last written element. *stdout* should be waiting until it sees that it's pointer is less than *stdin*'s pointer, and when this is the case it should write the elements of the buffer to **stdout** and update its own buffer after every write.

This is basically Lamport's algorithm but for two threads, one producer and one consumer.

When one thread is reading or writing to/from the buffer you *might* need to block the other thread from reading/writing in order to eliminate race conditions in your code.

Hope this helps.